# Converting double to string giving unexpected output

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have,

```
double d = 0.005;
d = d/100;
string str = Convert.ToString(d);

output of str = 5E-05
```

But I need output as 0.00005
While converting to string 0.00005 become 5E-05.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a IFormatProvider:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/iformatprovider-numbers/ 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tdhaxxa.aspx

EDIT: The above poster give you more details.

```
using System;

namespace test1{
    class MainClass {
        public static void Main (string[] args)     {
            double d = 0.005;
            d = d/100;
            string str = String.Format("{0:0.#####}",d);
            Console.WriteLine ("The double converted to String:  "+str);
        }
    }
}
```

This should compile and show what you want.

It can't get any more clear than this

Edit:
For more concrete examples look here: `

> http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

`

Comment: @Sahil : I edited my post for a more comprehensive answer. You need to look at the documentation more throughly, so you can solve things by yourself.

Comment: This is correct for one value which I have provided. But If I have value like 0.0005 then it is not working... Because my double value is not static, it is changing depends on user input.

Comment: Just one more # for each position

Answer (score 1):

You want to specify a format with which to convert the double to a string. `Double.ToString` does not let you do that (it uses scientific notation), so you should use `String.Format`, instead.

Here's your code, updated:

`string str = String.Format("{0:0.#####}", 0.00005);`

In fact, Double.ToString actually uses String.Format under the hood. See this link for more: [MSDN docs about `Double.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tostring%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Please see the following link for more examples of `String.Format`:
[Examples of using `String.Format`](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/)

Comment: Of course `Double.ToString` allows that. You just overlooked the overload.

Comment: Note that the other poster used some of my information. Please give credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
 string str = d.ToString("F99").TrimEnd("0".ToCharArray());
```

It is working fine. But what exactly this is doing that I don't know. This working for dynamic double value.

Thnks for both of you, who replied.